# Date Scalar Function to display 1st day or last day of the Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to create a function which takes in the current date and display either the beginning of the month or the end of the month if it has passed the half way point.
But im not sure  how to go around it

```sql
Declare  @todate  datetime ='20200301'

select
Case When DAY(@todate) > 15
Then Cast(DATEADD(dd, -( DAY( @todate ) -1 ), @todate) as date)  --- first day of the month 
else 
Cast(DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @todate) + 1, 0))as date)  --- last day of the month 
end
```

Comment: what's the trouble your having? create function syntax can be read on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: So >15th for 30/31 days? >14th for a February with 28/29 days?

Comment: Do you have `eomonth()` available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a single expression. I have used CROSS APPLY here to eliminate duplication of the code.

Here is some sample data:

```
DECLARE @testData (some_date datetime);
 INSERT INTO @testData (some_date)
 VALUES ('2023-02-14'), ('2023-02-15'), ('2023-02-16')
      , ('2023-03-14'), ('2023-03-15'), ('2023-03-16')
      , ('2023-06-14'), ('2023-06-15'), ('2023-06-16');
```

Here is sample code:

```
 SELECT td.some_date
      , first_this_month = dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, td.some_date), 0)
      , first_next_month = dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, td.some_date) + 1, 0)
      , first_or_last    = dateadd(DAY, -m.eom_flag, dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, td.some_date) + m.eom_flag, 0))
  FROM @testData AS td
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (iif(day(td.some_date) > day(eomonth(td.some_date)) / 2, 1, 0))) AS m(eom_flag);
```

If getting end of month (eom_flag = 1) - subtract 1 day from first of next month else return first of this month.

Or - you can use the following to return just a DATE:

```
 SELECT td.some_date
      , first_this_month = dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, td.some_date), 0)
      , first_next_month = dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, td.some_date) + 1, 0)
      , first_or_last    = iif(m.eom_flag = 1, eomonth(td.some_date), dateadd(DAY, 1, eomonth(td.some_date, -1)))
  FROM @testData AS td
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (iif(day(td.some_date) > day(eomonth(td.some_date)) / 2, 1, 0))) AS m(eom_flag);
```

Thought about this some more and we can simplify it even further:

```
 SELECT td.some_date
      , first_this_month = dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, td.some_date), 0)
      , first_next_month = dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, td.some_date) + 1, 0)
      , first_or_last    = dateadd(DAY, m.fom_flag, eomonth(td.some_date, -m.fom_flag))
  FROM @testData AS td
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (iif(day(td.some_date) > day(eomonth(td.some_date)) / 2, 0, 1))) AS m(fom_flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare  @todate  datetime ='20200104'
select iif(
     DATEPART(day,@todate)>15 ,
     DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @todate), 0)
    ,EOMONTH(@todate)  --Version 2022
--Version less than 2022(Other ways) :dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1 -datepart(day,@todate), @todate)))
)
--20200104 Result:2020-01-31 00:00:00.000
--20200118 Result:2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

you can use this is code  find  first day of the month

```
 DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @todate), 0)
```

you can use EOMONTH(Version 2022) or Version less than 2022(Other ways)  find last day of the month

Version 2022

```
EOMONTH ( start_date [, month_to_add ] )
```

[eomonth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Version less than 2022

```
dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(day,@todate), @todate)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting the day part from any given date will take you to the last date of the previous month, and adding 1 day to that day will get you the first date of the month.

```
--TO GET THE FIRST DATE OF THE MONTH
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + 1;
```

Similarly, adding one month to the date and subtracting the day part will get you the last date of the month.

```
--TO GET THE LAST DATE OF THE MONTH
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,1) - DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,1));
```

Next, the if else condition.

```
--IF 15 DAYS HAVE PASSED IN THE MONTH, OUTPUT SHOULD BE THE LAST DATE OF THE MONTH 
--ELSE, FIRST DATE OF THE MONTH
SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) > 15 THEN
ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,1) - DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,1))--LAST DATE
ELSE CURRENT_DATE - DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + 1--FIRST DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function:

```
create or alter function dbo.MyFunction(@Date date)
returns date
as
begin
  return (
    select case 
      when Day(@date) > Day(EOMonth(@date)) / 2.0 
      then EOMonth(@date) 
      else DateTimeFromParts(Year(@date), Month(@date),1,0,0,0,0) 
      end
    )
end;
```

Examples:

```
select dbo.MyFunction('20230110');
```

Result: 2023-01-01

```
select dbo.MyFunction('20230116');
```

Result: 2023-01-31

```
select dbo.MyFunction('20200215')
```

Result: 2020-02-29

Comment: You shouldn't mix DATE and DATETIME data types in your case expression.  The return for the function is date so you should just use DATEFROMPARTS since EOMONTH already returns a date data type.